# Wordpress pages caused permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I had wordpress site with permalink based on post name.

I had to recreate the entire server.   The tables data is same.

Now, the pages will not be recognized if i keep permalink to post name.  if I change to permalink to plan (http://www.imtftrade.com/?p=123), it works.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check *.htaccess* file in your root directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Also, go to *“Settings” > “Permalinks” > “Common settings”*, and set the radio button to *“Custom Structure”*. Use templates below that field to set up links path. Don't forget to press the Save button.

Let me know if it helped! Good luck